# alert when url is exact url and not containing other parameters

Tags: javascript, url

I've got two urls:

1. http://stackoverflow.com
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I want to alert when the url is http://stackoverflow.com and not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

```
if (location.href == "http://stackoverflow.com") {
   alert ('hello');
}
```

Why does it also alert when the url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?

Comment: It shouldn't do that. Can you show a real world example?

Comment: try window.location.href

Comment: @ Pekka - Why shouldn't it do that? How can I prevent this behaviour? This example is a real world example. It's a Greasemonkeyscript.

Comment: @Emmanuel - unfortunately it doesn't work. Any other idea?

Comment: Just before your if statment add alert(window.location.href); just to see whats it is...

Comment: @Emmanuel - it was what you said. Thank you. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @urir - Answer posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!window.location.pathname) {
   alert ('hello');
}
```

**edit**

Okay, so the answer was to use window.location.href rather than location.href, like this:

```
if (window.location.href == "http://stackoverflow.com") {
   alert ('hello');
}
```

Comment: Yes, the update needed some time. Thank you very much. I'll mark it as answered asap.

Comment: Okay, no worries. I"m glad it's sorted out for you.